# Ubuntu 13.04 speakers making no sound after booting?

Tags: sound, 13.04, speakers

I get this weird issue when you boot a certain time into 13.04, the sound doesn't work. Restarting the computer fixes the sound and nothing seems to be wrong after that. Would this be considered a bug? When that one time the booting causes the no sound problem, you can see a field of codes and text something you would see in the terminal. I'm assuming that might be kernel or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem and I'm trying to find the reason for it. Could you clarify some simple things real quick? - Are you using a desktop or laptop? If it's a laptop, what kind. - Does your headphone jack still work when this happens? - If possible could you check if your microphone works when this happens? - Is your computer just ubuntu or is it dual with windows or other? My laptop also freezes when I attempt to shutdown or restart when the problem occurs. I force it off and when it I restart the sound works again. Have you had this problem at all?

Comment: @bmp You are rite I'm experiencing the same thing you listed... No sound tried to restart but got hung. Force restart and it works. I use a Lenevo Thinkpad with 13.04

Comment: My fix for this problem was upgrading the kernel and booting since then has improved.

Comment: @MichaelScott I have this version now and the sound from my laptop is working but when i plugin speakers jack then no ouput "Linux rsz 3.9.0-030900-generic #201304291257 SMP Mon Apr 29 16:58:15 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Answer (score 0):

Entering

`sudo alsa force-reload`

in the terminal is the only solution I've found

Comment: This might help. http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-3-9-kernel-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04-and-linux-mint-15-14-13/

Answer (score 0):

The best solution if above not work is:

Open the terminal and edit speech-dispatcher file by using the following command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

In here, change `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no`

Reboot and enjoy sound.

Via http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip